# Is there a name for when the same word is used at the beginning and end of different phrases/sentences?

Tags: terminology, literary-techniques

Is there a name for when one phrase ends with a word that starts the next phrase. For instance:

> life is a peach and cream

Or

> sunscreen in the eye for detail

Or (from Dave Eggers' *Heartbreaking Work of Staggering Genius*)

> JFKFC

Comment: I don't understand your examples (puzzled face). None of your sentences begin with the last word of the previous phrase. And what is JFKC??

Comment: Good point. Perhaps writersSE have an answer. Or just show some patience over here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA life is a *peach* + *peach* and cream; JFK + KFC -- imagine!

Comment: Looks like it's some literary technique or improvisation. Let's watch what happens.

Comment: There is an entire category of puzzles on the American TV game show "Wheel of Fortune" dedicated to this style of word play, which they call "Before & After". For example: "Beer nuts and bolts", "A sheepish grin and bear it", "Adam's apple of my eye". A nearly exhaustive list of past phrases can be found [here](http://wheeloffortuneanswer.com/before-and-after/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are describing *word association football*, a variation on the classic rhetorical device *anadiplosis*, “the repetition of the last word (or phrase) from the previous line, clause, or sentence at the beginning of the next”.<sup>[1](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/A/anadiplosis.htm)</sup> In this variation, anadiplosis is combined with *ellipsis*, “omission of a word or short phrase easily understood in context”.<sup>[2](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/E/ellipsis.htm)</sup>

Word association football is essentially surprising in a humorous and literary sort of way, like a pun. Your examples are typical.

While not necessarily the originators of this rhetorical device, Monty Python get widespread credit for naming it.<sup>[4](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/414500.html)</sup> The name stems from one of their monologues.

Here is an example of anadiplosis, followed by the canonical example of word association football. Bolding, italics, and line breaks are added to emphasize the rhetorical structure.

> ### Glad You Came (example of anadiplosis)
>
> Turn the lights out **now**
>   **Now**, I'll take you by the **hand**
>   **Hand** you another **drink**
>   **Drink** it if you **can**
>   **Can** you spend a little **time**
>   **Time** is slipping **away**
>   **Away** from us, so **stay**
>   **Stay** with me I can **make**
>   **Make** you glad you came
>   —*The Wanted*<sup>[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadiplosis)</sup>
>
> ### Word Association Football
>
> **Tonight**’s the night
>   **I shall be talking about** of flu
>   **the subject of word association** football.
>   **This is a technique** out a living
>   **much used in the practice** makes perfect
>   **of psychoanalysis**ter and brother
>   **and one that has occupied** piper
>   **the majority** rule
>   **of my attention** squad by the right number one two three
>   **fo***u***r the last five years** to the memory.
>   **It is quite remarkable** baker charlie
>   **how much** the miller’s son
>   **this so-called** while you were out
>   **word association** immigrants’ problems
>   **influences the manner** from heaven
>   **in which we** sleekit cowering timrous beasties *all-American*
>   **speak**, the famous explorer.
>   **And the really** well that is
>   **surprising part**ner in crime
>   **is that a lot** and his wife
>   **of the** lions’ feeding
>   **time we may be** c d e
>   **effectively quite unaware of the fact** or fiction section of the Watford Public Library
>   **that we are even doing it** is a far, far better thing that I do now *then, now then, what's going On*ward Christian *Barnard the famous heart*y part of the lettuce *now praise famous men*tal homes for loonies like me.
>   **So** on the button,
>   **my contention** causing all the headaches,
>   **is that unless we take into account** of Monte Cristo
>   **in our thinking** George the Fifth
>   **this phenomenon** the other hand
>   **we shall not be able satisfactor** fiction section of the Watford Public Library again
>   **ily to understand** to attention when I’m talking to you and stop laughing
>   **about human nature, man’s psychological make-up** some story the wife’ll believe
>   **and hence the very meaning of life itself**ish bastard, I’ll kick him in the balls *Pond Road*.
>   —*Monty Python*

Comment: It could also be regarded as a [zeugma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma).

Comment: I was just thinking of this yesterday: Miss Susie had a steamboat. The steamboat had a bell. Miss Susie went to heaven and the steamboat went to hello, operator, give me number nine, and if you disconnect me, I'll paddle your behind the 'frigerator, there lay a piece of glass... and so on, that we used to sing on the bus in grade school and giggle over.