# What is it called when the last word of a sentence is also used as the first word of the next sentence?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

For example in the rhyme "[Miss Susie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Susie)" the end of each verse is linked to the next. Would these just be called puns? Or is there a more specific name when they are used in this way.

Example:

> Miss Susie had a steamboat,
>
> the steamboat had a bell.
>
> Miss Susie went to heaven
>
> and the steamboat went to Hell–
>
> -
>
> O, operator,
>
> please give me number nine...

The first verse ends with "Hell" which is merged into "Hello" in the next.

Comment: See

***anadiplosis***

in http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116987/is-there-a-name-for-when-the-same-word-is-used-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-diffe

Comment: The word the OP is looking for is clearly [**anadiplosis**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadiplosis), but the EL&U question (helpfully linked to by Mari-Lou A) where _anadiplosis_ is discussed is actually about a variant on anadiplosis where the shared—and would-be duplicate—word is given only once, and not necessarily at a break between two sentences, as in "home on the range rover." So perhaps this qualifies not as a "duplicate question" but as a "question that is answered elsewhere in response to a related but somewhat different question."